# EntityFramework Deleting Objects while Observing Collections and Property Changes

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, event-handling, observablecollection

I have an `EntityService` class which wraps around entity operations and also provides the WPF application `ObservableCollection`s of materialized entities.

When I come to delete a Book from my collection of `Books`:

```
<Class EntityService>

public void DeleteBook(Book book)
{
    context.DeleteObject(book)
    observableCollectionOfBooks.Remove(book)
}
```

`EntityFramework` then proceeds to null all the navigation properties of the to-be-deleted Book which fires off `PropertyChanged` events. One of my ViewModels is an observer of this event:

```
<Class LibraryViewModel>

private void BookPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Get all materialized books
    var books = entityService.Books.Where(x => x.Author.Name == "Dan");
}
```

Here I get a `NullReferenceException` because the deleted Book hasn't been removed from the `ObservableCollection` yet and the `Author` for the to-be-deleted `Book` is `null`.

I've tried changing the order of operations in `DeleteBook(Book book)` but it produces a different but related inconsistency.

The problem is that the operation is not atomic.

What I'm looking for is `BookPropertyChanged` to be called only when the model is in a consistent state: The `Book` is in deleted and the `ObservableCollection` doesn't contain the deleted object.

I realise there may be some hack to fix this such as checking for nulls but I was wondering if there was a better way?

I was thinking of somehow suppressing the events until both operations were completed. I'm not sure how this would work even in theory but I think I need to achieve something equivalent to the following:

```
using (new EventSuppressor(book, observableCollectionOfBooks))
{
    context.DeleteObject(book)
    observableCollectionOfBooks.Remove(book)
}
```

So here, any objects passed into the EventSuppressor constructor will have their event notifications suppressed and cached up. The operations inside the using block can take place. When the suppressor is disposed, all events that would have been fired due to the operations executed in the using block are now fired.

Answer (score 0):

I may be way off, but,  what if you try the below?

```
public void DeleteBook(Book book)
{
    context.DeleteObject(book);
    context.SaveChanges();
    observableCollectionOfBooks.Remove(book);
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't make any difference since it is the DeleteObject that raises the PropertyChangedEvent. What I really need is for both DeleteObject and ObservableCollection.Remove to be exectuted before any events are fired. That way, the Model and object graph would be consistent as the application layer expects.